# MySql Query, Select greater than

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a table, called faq_questions with the following structure:

```
id int not_null auto_increment,
question varchar(255),
sort_order int
```

I'm attempting to build a query that given a sort order, selects the row with the next highest sort order.

Example:

```
id  question                sort_order
1   'This is question 1'    10
2   'This is question 2'    9
3   'This is another'       8
4   'This is another one'   5
5   'This is yet another'   4
```

Ok, so imagine I pass in 5 for my known sort order (id 4), I need it to return the row with id 3.  Since there's no guarantee that sort_order will be contiguous I can't just select known_sort_order + 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems too simple, but it looks like what you need:

```
SELECT id,question FROM `questions` 
WHERE `sort_order` > sort_order_variable
ORDER BY sort_order ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Be sure to ORDER BY sort_order DESC otherwise you will get weird results

Comment: ASC, since he wants the next lowest entry

Comment: Whoops, I saw ID = 3 and thought he meant sort_order =3 . You got it :D

Comment: And there's no reason to put quotes around the sort order variable if it's an integer (and it might interfere with the optimizer).

Comment: < since he wants the next lowest (3 < 5)

Comment: It *will* interfere with the optimizer, from my personal experience.

Comment: @Eran: He wants the row with sort_order = 8, not 3.

Comment: You're right... he confused me with the id numbering in his question. Fixed

Comment: If the table has many many entries with `sort_order > sort_order_variable` , would that be slow? I imagine we would have to sort all those rows every time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sort_order > 5 ORDER BY sort_order ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `TOP` or `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM faq_questions
WHERE sort_order > 5
ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

but that's not as elegant or portable as

```
SELECT *  
FROM faq_questions AS f1  
LEFT JOIN faq_questions AS f2  
    ON f1.sort_order > f2.sort_order  
    AND f2.sort_order = 5  
LEFT JOIN faq_questions AS f3  
    ON f3.sort_order BETWEEN f1.sort_order AND f2.sort_order  
WHERE f3.id IS NULL
```

Comment: "TOP N" is a nonstandard Microsoft/Sybase feature.  MySQL does not support it.

Comment: Right, that's why I put LIMIT (since I didn't notice the title, the only place where MySQL was identified.) :) Is LIMIT an SQL standard?

Comment: No, LIMIT is nonstandard SQL.  As far as I know, it's supported only by MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite.

Comment: That's what I thought - any record-count limit is non-standard (which Codd and Date would appreciate, I imagine.) So my "portable" assertion is ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id, question, sort_order
FROM faq_questions 
WHERE sort_order in 
(SELECT 
        MIN(sort_order) 
    FROM faq_questions 
    WHERE sort_order > ?);
```

That seems to work

Comment: Yes, that works.  You can also use = instead of IN, since the subquery returns a single value.