# SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 is greater than column1

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multiple-conditions

[image: sample table]

I want to display all values of a column that is greater than its equivalent value in another row

Like for example,
Display country name WHERE population is greater than country name (i.e. Andorra)

```
SELECT name FROM country
WHERE population > population (of Andorra)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql Query, Select greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360961/mysql-query-select-greater-than)

Comment: That's another 'row', not another 'column'

Comment: @Strawberry thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT name
FROM country
WHERE population > (
   SELECT population
   FROM country 
   WHERE name = 'Andorra'
);
```

Please note that this query will return an error if

- there is no record with name country name 'Andorra' or
- there is more than one record with country name 'Andorra'

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM country
WHERE population > (SELECT population FROM country WHERE name = 'Andorra')
```

You think something like this?